# MYSQL accepts a string value with letters for an INT datatype

Tags: php, mysql, get

I'm using php and mysql. When a user clicks submit button the GET query string is like this:

`http://mywebsite.com/category/section?article=1`

And I query like this:

> "SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE `art_id`='$article' "

`art_id` is an `int(11)` datatype but it accepts a value with letters if I have the correct number as prefix like : `http://mywebsite.com/category/section?article=1asd`. If I pass all letters (`?article=asd`) it won't accept but if I pass a number with letter (`?article=12asd`) it does accept and returns the article with `art_id` of `12`. How can I prevent this?

I've tried it directly on MySQL command line client and it accepts the value with letters in it.

Comment: Just remove the single quotes around the variable in the statement `art_id='$article'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check in your code by if condition:

```
You can check your GET variable 'article' before passing into mysql query to prevent the issue you are facing:
solution 1: if(is_numeric($_GET['article'])){your query}
solution 2: intval($_GET['article']);//cast the variable and then pass into query
solution 3: if(is_int($_GET['article'])){your query}
```

Hope these solutions work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your table change `int(11)` to `varchar(11)` provided it is not a `PK` ..In this scnerio you can include variable charecters

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
If(isset($_GET['article']) && (is_numeric($_GET['article'])){your query}
// Add isset function for unset viarables and is_numeric function numeric validation.
Good luck!